# How can I execute one-time/less frequent commands with docker-compose up

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose up file that brings up my application

```
version: '3'
services:
  web-app:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "36081:36081"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MIGRATE: Y
      DB_1_HOST: db1
      DB_1_PORT: 3306
      DB_2_HOST: db2
      DB_2_PORT: 3306
  db1:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7
    environment: 
      MYSQL_DATABASE: config_dev
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
    volumes:
      - ./docker/images/db1/sql-scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - db1-volume:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "1200:3306"
  db1:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7
    environment: 
      MYSQL_DATABASE: config_dev
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
    volumes:
      - ./docker/images/db2/sql-scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - db2-volume:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "1201:3306"
```

web-app is built from a Dockerfile that has the following entrypoint

```
ENTRYPOINT /usr/src/app/docker-entrypoint.sh
```

The `docker-entrypoint.sh` script has the commands that are required to run to start the application. However, I have a few commands like migrating the database schema and seeding new data (I have scripts for those that need to run from my web-app container) which need to be run either only one-time or with less frequently than the others.

For instance, a developer might want to run the migrate script once in a month to accommodate any new schema changes that might have occurred. 

My current solution for this is using an environment variable `MIGRATE` in the web-app service of `docker-compose.yml` and use the value of the variable in the `docker-entrypoint.sh` to decide which command to run. (If Y, run migrate commands along with usual startup commands, if N  run only usual startup commands). I want to improve this design.

- Can I create custom docker-compose commands? (`docker-compose up init` to migrate and then run, `docker-compose up` only run)
- Is there any other better approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`docker-compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/) an arbitrary command in a new container that's (mostly) the same as one of the containers you describe in your `docker-compose.yml` file

```
docker-compose run web-app ./manage.py migrate
```

The trick with doing this is that your entrypoint script needs to make sure to execute the "command" part of the `docker run` command, which it gets as command-line arguments.  If it's a shell script, it can end with the line

```
exec "$@"
```

In your Dockerfile, this means you need to both specify the `ENTRYPOINT` and the default `CMD` to run.  The `ENTRYPOINT` must use the JSON-array form.  `CMD` may be either the JSON-array form or a bare string.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Since the entrypoint script is ultimately responsible for running the entire container you can make up commands to run.  You've probably already done this with checking a `$MIGRATE` environment variable.  It's common to use an entrypoint script to do this sort of thing as setup before running the main container command, but you can also just replace the command entirely.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -e

# Run migrations if requested (possibly in addition to another command)
if [ "$MIGRATE" = "y" ] || [ "$1" = "migrate" ]; then
  ./manage.py migrate
fi

# Run the `command:`, `CMD`, or command-line command
case "$1" of
  migrate)
    # already done above
    exit 0
    ;;
  seed)
    exec ./manage.py loaddata "$@"
    ;;
  *)
    exec "$@"
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, I will go through `docker-compose run` in the documentation too!

Comment: Hey, can you clarify how ENTRYPOINT and CMD would be different in this case?

Comment: CMD is passed as arguments to ENTRYPOINT; that combined command (here `docker-entrypoint.sh /bin/sh -c 'python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`) is the main container process.  [Understand how CMD and ENTRYPOINT interact](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) in the Dockerfile documentation goes into more detail.  You can override the two parts separately at runtime, and if you `docker run imagename some command` outside a Compose context that overrides only the CMD.

Comment: Using `docker-compose run` I am unable to start up the dependent service entrypoints, as a result I am unable to run my command. What would be the workaround that? Described this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60445625/docker-compose-run-does-not-run-the-entrypoint-scripts-of-dependent-services