# docker-compose run does not run the entrypoint scripts of dependent services

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run a one time command on my application container using the command

```
docker-compose run --entrypoint="/usr/src/app/migrate.sh" app
```

`app` is the name of my service and the said entrypoint contains the one-time command that I'm trying to run.
Here's my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    # mount the current directory (on the host) to /usr/src/app on the container, any changes in either would be reflected in both the host and the container
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    # expose application on localhost:36081
    ports:
      - "36081:36081"
    # application restarts if stops for any reason - required for the container to restart when the application fails to start due to the database containers not being ready
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db1
      - db2
    # the environment variables are used in docker/config/env_config.rb to connect to different database containers
    environment:
      MYSQL_DB1_HOST: db1
      MYSQL_DB1_PORT: 3306
      MYSQL_DB2_HOST: db2
      MYSQL_DB2_PORT: 3306
  db1:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7
    environment: 
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test1
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
    # mount volume of the schema script to /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d to execute the script on startup  
    volumes:
      - ./docker/seed/db1:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - db1-volume:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    # to connect locally from SequelPro
    ports:
      - "1200:3306"
  db2:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7
    environment: 
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test2
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
    # mount volume of the schema script to /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d to execute the script on startup  
    volumes:
      - ./docker/seed/db2:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - db2-volume:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    # to connect locally from SequelPro
    ports:
      - "1201:3306"
```

Everything works as expected when I start `docker-compose up`, but when I invoke `docker-compose run`, the dependent services `db1` and `db2` containers are up, but they are not initialised with the entrypoint script(as a result the mySQL database is not created). The volume is attached though.

How can I ensure that the entrypoint script of the dependent containers is invoked as well?

Comment: I'm confused by what behavior you're expecting.  `db1` and `db2` are running; you launch an additional container overriding its entrypoint; what do you expect to happen in the databases, and why?

Comment: I'm only overriding the entrypoint of app, since it depends on db1 and db2, they start up however they do not execute their own entrypoint scripts on startup (which has SQL files that populate data in them).

Comment: Do the `db1-volume` and `db2-volume` still exist?  The `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` scripts only get run if the database is starting up the very first time.

Comment: I made sure that I remove all the volumes before starting it up. `docker-compose run` is creating the fresh volumes but not running the script.